# How to run a javascript function that checks if a username is available

Tags: javascript

I'm building a javascript function that receives an input and checks it against stored objects in an array to see if it matches against any

The if else statement don't work

```
const accounts = []; //holds all user name and password

function getinput() {
  let pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
  let user = document.getElementById("username").value;

  let newuser = {
    username: user,
    password: pass,
  };

  let match = (toMatch) => toMatch === newuser.username
  if (accounts.some(match) === true) {
    return alert("choose another `username");
  }
  accounts.push(newuser)
  return alert("account created")
};
var clik = document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click", getinput);
```

It should tell the user if a username is available or not

Comment: `let match = (toMatch) => toMatch.username === newuser.username`? You also have some severe formatting issues that seem to be obscuring other errors in your code, e.g. `if(… )}`

Comment: Can you please provide a working code example and input to reprduce your problem

Comment: Thanks p.s.w.g Im new to coding I'll definitely work on my formatting

Comment: `addEventListener` doesn't return anything, there's no point in assigning it to `clik`.

Comment: Tamir klein I don't know how to do that could you please walk me through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct answer to your question would be along the lines of:

```
function getInput() {
    /* store the value of the input */
    var current_userName = document.getElementById("username").value;

    /* check if that value already exists in the accounts Array */
    var matched = accounts.find(account => account.username === current_userName);

    /* conditional for each of the two cases */
    if (!matched) {
        /* code if username is available */
    } else {
        /* code if username is NOT available */
    }
};

document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click" , getInput);
```

You have some mistakes in your code, which need fixing.

Also, look into `Array.prototype.find()` for more info.

Hope this will help you get started in the right direction. Best of luck!

Comment: Don't need `return` word after arrow.

Comment: my bad, forgot about the arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

Finally understood what I was doing wrong had to point toMatch of accounts to check for username contained within the array of object

```
const  = [ ]; //holds all user name and password

function getinput() {
  let pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
  let user = document.getElementById("username").value;

  let newuser = {
    username: user,
    password: pass,
  };
//this was where I got it wrong I was doing toMatch === newuser.username which was wrong 

  let match = (toMatch) => toMatch.username === user
  if (accounts.some(match) === true) {
    return alert("choose another username");
  }
  accounts.push(newuser)
  return alert("account created")
};
document.getElementById("login
```